# How to insert a text?

Tags: bash

`foo.txt` consists of

```
printf("%f \n\n",row1.req_pnttime);
printf("%f \n\n",avinash);
printf("%f \n\n",foo);
printf("%f \n\n",bar);
```

`bar.txt` consists of,

```
foo
bar
foo1
bar1
```

I want to combine first line of bar.txt with the first line of foo.txt in a specified place.Same for all the lines.Like below,

Expected output:

```
printf("foo%f \n\n",row1.req_pnttime);
printf("bar%f \n\n",avinash);
printf("foo1%f \n\n",foo);
printf("bar1%f \n\n",bar);
```

I tried the below , but it won't work.

```
awk -v FS="\"" -v OFS="\"" 'FNR==NR{a=$0;}{$2=a[FNR]$2}1' bar.txt foo.txt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this,

```
sed 'R bar.txt' foo.txt | sed 'N;s/^\(.*\)\(%.*\)\n\(.*\)/\1\3\2/'
```

**Test**:

```
sat:~# sed 'R bar.txt' foo.txt | sed 'N;s/^\(.*\)\(%.*\)\n\(.*\)/\1\3\2/'
printf("foo%f \n\n",row1.req_pnttime);
printf("bar%f \n\n",avinash);
printf("foo1%f \n\n",foo);
printf("bar1%f \n\n",bar);
```

Comment: @AvinashRaj, `R bar.txt` will read each line from `bar.txt` and output it. So, the output will be, one line from `foo.txt` and one line from `bar.txt`. Then, I'm using `sed`(another) to rearrange the format.

Comment: i correlate your answer with [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/444365/202806) answer. It's almost similar but i can't get the second sed part.Please explain the second one for me.

Comment: @AvinashRaj, `N` will read next line and append into buffer. Now, You have two lines (one from `foo.txt` and another one from `bar.txt`) in buffer. Two lines are separated by newline(`\n`). **Eg:** `printf("%f \n\n",row1.req_pnttime);\nfoo` . Then, I am just grouping the data and rearranging it by using back reference( `\1`,`\2`..).

Answer (score 3):

Ok, i figured out the problem. One through awk,

```
$ awk -v FS="\"" -v OFS="\"" 'FNR==NR{a[FNR]=$0;next}{$2=a[FNR]$2}1' bar.txt foo.txt
printf("foo%f \n\n",row1.req_pnttime);
printf("bar%f \n\n",avinash);
printf("foo1%f \n\n",foo);
printf("bar1%f \n\n",bar);
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the text is always aligned to the same column you could do this:

```
cut -b1-8 foo.txt > a
cut -b9- foo.txt > b
paste -d '' a bar.txt b
```